# GCM(google cloud messaging) push notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use GCM push notifications. My device is registered to the server and I've created the device registration id as well. But when I'm trying to send a message from my server,the message does not go to the registered device. Can anyone please help me?

**My Main Activity**

package com.ati.gcm;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.ati.gcm.CommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION;

import static com.ati.gcm.CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

import static com.ati.gcm.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
// label to display gcm messages
TextView lblMessage;
 
// Asyntask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
 
// Alert dialog manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
 
// Connection detector
ConnectionDetector cd;
 
public static String name;
public static String email;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }
     
    // Getting name, email from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();
     
    name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    email = i.getStringExtra("email");     
     
    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);
     
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
     
    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Registration is not present, register now with GCM          
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // Skips registration.             
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}      

/**
 * Receiving push messages
 * */
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());
         
        /**
         * Take appropriate action on this message
         * depending upon your app requirement
         * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
         * */
         
        // Showing received message
        lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");          
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         
        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
 
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mRegisterTask != null) {
        mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Post code of your broadcast receiver?

Comment: Check your API key. Have you got unauthorized error while send a message to device? Show code for your receiver too.

Comment: post code of your receiver n manifest

Comment: Take look at [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd8bIkE29U4&list=WL&index=8) for demo of implementing GCM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Did you send client's GCM id of  to your Server,  Server communicate with client through that id and GCM server.
- have you inserted GCM permission to your manifest?
- Whether or not Gcmintentservice.java located in main package of your project?

Comment: i am checking all your suggestion but could not work. thank you.

Comment: Thank you. yea my API key was wrong. i am creating a new project and using the new API key , it is working well.